# How to include a project in another project using ClassLoader

Tags: java, eclipse

i want have access of a project(like it classes) into another project.Can i use ClasLoader for that?  If so how can i do that?

Ex-I want to access classes in Project A in  Project B.

Comment: This is not making a lot of sense to me.  Are you talking about IDE projects?  Maven projects?

Comment: any java project in workspace

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about Eclipse and you want the classes of "Project A" to be accessible to the code of "Project B":

Right click on "Project B" -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> "Add..." -> Add a check-mark next to "Project A" -> OK

Answer (score 0):

Because of your tag (eclipse) I suppose you have 2 bundles and you want to access from one bundle to another bundles classes. In OSGI this is done using Export-Package and Import-Package properties in the bundle manifest file.

Hope it helps